# how to receive a packet of bytes and words (two bytes) and septate them in vb6 or vb express 2010

Tags: vb6, microcontroller

I want to connect an 8 bit micro-controller to my PC using VB6 6 or Visual Basic Express Edition 2010.

My information contains some 2-byte words and some byte information for example 4 or 5 bytes.
I am capable of storing this information in a string of hex numbers from micro-controller side, but I'm having difficulty separating and using the information in Visual Basic.

I want to convert the word data from hex to decimal and display this in labels. My byte data is 8-bit digital information. I want to use this by separating each byte into individual bits  and glowing some bulbs to indicate some of my micro-controller's port 8 bit status. I have done some practical already but not to my satisfaction.

Comment: some code and sample data as well as formatting would help us a lot...

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim b1 as Byte, b2 as Byte
Dim word as Integer
Dim bit5_On as Boolean

word = LShift(b1,8) or b2

bit5_On = ((b1 and 16) = 16)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already set up a serial transmission between the PC and the micro, and see bytes coming, then the followings may apply.

First you might have coded something in the micro where you intend to send the data. This code might run multiple times thus sending the data repeatedly (intentionally). In the micro you see where you divide up the data, but that does not mean you would inherently see this on the PC side.

On the PC side you essentially see a continuous stream of data which you may or may not be able to separate on the intended boundaries.

The solution is creating a protocol. The simplest is to make the micro only sending data if the PC side requests it (by sending some request command, for example just a single byte, to the micro). Then when the PC side receives the answer, it can know that it is a single piece of data, and so is able to break it up accordingly.

An other way is to let the micro continuously send data. Then the key is creating proper packet frames, that is indicators in the stream that new data is coming. If you for example send BCD numbers, then a 0xFF character may be fine for this purpose.